# Autolayout With UILabel Behavior is Unexplainable

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, autolayout

I have a super basic program where I am trying to figure out how autolayout works. This is my storyboard:

[image]

The TableViewController orientation setting is "inferred".
The numberOfLines setting has been set to 0. 
The "long text~" UILabel is supposed to be about "Default" pixels to the right of "random label" and 45 pixels as a trailing space from the UITableViewCell.

This is my result in simulator in portrait mode:

[image]

As you can see, it is 100% what you would expect.

However this is what we see in landscape mode:

[image]

What happened in landscape mode? Why did all my text shift down a little? The UILabel is supposed to be only 4 pixels from the top of the cell. Can anyone explain this??

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't have enough reputation to post URLS.
Here is what it looks like in portrait mode:
http://postimg.org/image/ifu4qdhv7/

As you can see, it is 100% what I expect. However landscape mode is not.

Comment: Add a `backgroundColor` to the label. I guess you will see that the label indeed has the size that you want it to, but it is too large for the shown text (it centers the text vertically).

Comment: it seems that your long text UILabel have auto-wrapped when in landscape. Can you post your code or settings what did you leave or set in your label in the attributes inspector.

Comment: Hey Pascal, thanks for answering. I did this and realized that you were right. All I had to do was call [UILABEL sizeToFit]. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue!

Hey Pascal, thanks for answering. I did this and realized that you were right. All I had to do was call [UILABEL sizeToFit]. Thanks for your help :D – Woodless 19 hours ago